# Giving name and price to pictures of foods

Tags: android

I am working On a Food Management Project In android .I have created a gallery and want that when any user touch any of the picture that i have used in that look with a description That what is the name of that food and price of that food .After That i want to add the Online payment process in that.What Should  Be code and Process to achieve this task.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't there to do the work for you. We are happy to help if you have a specific problem with a piece of code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

For implement image gallery you can refer to this

[Builng image gallery](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)